# Can't pass /bin/*

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to pass a to fill an array with a list of directories using a simple shell script. However when I pass `/bin/*` into the program as the first parameter `$1` turn to `/bin/bash` (the first directory in /bin). My code is below for reference. Can I not pass `*` in a parameter?

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a d
placeholder=0

for filename in ${1}; do
     d[${placeholder}]=${filename:5}
     ((placeholder++))
 done

echo "$1"
```

The result of the echo is `/bin/bash`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A glob is replaced by the shell with a list of names it matches.

Take advantage of this, and read the list of names passed on your argument list:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a d
placeholder=0

for filename in "$@"; do               # or just ''for filename; do''
     d[${placeholder}]=${filename:5}
     ((placeholder++))
done

# print your array
declare -p d

# or, to print your array's contents one entry per line:
printf '%s\n' "${d[@]}"
```

...or, far easier:

```
#!/bin/bash
d=( "${@##*/}" )           # assuming the :5 is intended to leave only filenames
declare -p d
```

Answer (score 0):

`*` is being expanded by the shell before it calls your script. Try calling as `yourscript '/bin/*'` (note the quotes).

Comment: Thanks that worked! May I ask what you mean by "expanded"?

Comment: Search for "bash expand glob" and you should get a whole lot of useful info.

Comment: This is bad advice. If the OP were trying to search for `"prefix with spaces"*.txt`, it would fail utterly (their `for filename in $1` would first iterate over `prefix`, then `with`, then the result of expanding the glob `spaces*.txt`).